# How to get user name from email address using DAX formula in SSAS tabular model

Tags: ssas, dax

I have a SSAS Tabular Cube an I am getting data from a underlying Database.

I have a table Employee with columns:
Job Title
EmployeeID (Some numeric ID)
Email Address
Full Name
Department

I have email address like this
Data in column - kunalshukla@yahoo.com (just example)

Want to extract - kunalshukla and clear @yahoo.com

I want a DAX formula which is simple to do this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked just fine for me without the `?`:

```
= LEFT(Employee[Email Address], FIND("@", Employee[Email Address],,1) - 1)
```

This does too:

```
= LEFT(Employee[Email Address], SEARCH("?@", Employee[Email Address],,BLANK()))
```

I recommend leaving out the `yahoo.com` part so it doesn't break if you happen to have a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and was able to get the expected result using below formula in DAX Tabular Model (SSAS)

=MID(Employee[Email Address],1,SEARCH("?@yahoo.com",Employee[Email Address],,BLANK()))

- Here I am using "?" as wildcard search without that it will give error as:

"An argument of the MID has the wrong data type or has an invalid data value"

Also note that SEARCH, FIND functions are unable to find the special character "@" if given without a "?" before it.

Let me know if you find this helpful